# What does the switch -r mean for Firebird gbak tool?

Tags: backup, firebird

When I run:

```
gbak -r
```

what will it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebird < 2.0, -r will replace your currently database file with the one restored from the backup. In FB >= 2.0, you need to specify -rep for that. Take care to avoid replacing an active database.

Answer (score 2):

```
-r[ecreate_database] o[verwrite]
```

http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gbak.htm

> [Firebird 2.0] Restores over an existing database. This can only be performed by SYSDBA or the owner of the database that is overwritten. Do NOT restore over a database that is in use!
>   -r is equivalent to -c. Only the "overwrite" option will restore over an existing database.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces the database - ie. overwrites it.

http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gbak